# Pandas merge displaying columns from single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm joining two dataframes using merge in pandas, but the result contains columns from single dataframe. Here is the piece of code:

```
df1
date(index) | Total | Unique

df2
date(index) | Total | Unique

result = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="inner")
Output:
Total | Unqiue

Expected Output:
df1_Total | df2_Unique | df2_total |  df2_unique
```

I've also tried suffixes, but they doesn't work as well.

Comment: What is your join key? `pd.merge` is joining `on` the following criteria if not stated: If on is None and not merging on indexes then this defaults to the intersection of the columns in both DataFrames.

Answer (score 2):

```
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="inner", on='date(index)')
```

This will join on `date(index)`. Change your join key as necessary to what you require

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and `left_on` and `right_on` parameetrs, but get same values in both columns, because default inner join:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([(10,2),(20,4),(30,6)], 
                   columns=['Total','Unique'], 
                   index=pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=3))
df2 = pd.DataFrame([(10,2),(30,6),(20,600)], 
                    columns=['Total','Unique'], 
                    index=pd.date_range('2015-01-02', periods=3))

#print (df1)
#print (df2)

result = pd.merge(df1.add_prefix('df1_'), 
                  df2.add_prefix('df2_'),
                  left_on=['df1_Total','df1_Unique'],
                  right_on=['df2_Total','df2_Unique'])
print (result)
   df1_Total  df1_Unique  df2_Total  df2_Unique
0         10           2         10           2
1         30           6         30           6
```

If want join by index values is necessary use `left_index` and `right_index` with `suffixes`:

```
result = pd.merge(df1, 
                  df2,
                  left_index=True,
                  right_index=True,
                  suffixes=('_df1','_df2'))
print (result)
            Total_df1  Unique_df1  Total_df2  Unique_df2
2015-01-02         20           4         10           2
2015-01-03         30           6         30           6
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify merge function parameter on as 'Date' column

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how="inner", on="Date")
```